# Object reference not set to instance of object in mvc[Null Reference Exception]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an MVC application.I am getting an error of Null Reference Exception on change password form functionality.

### My Model class code

```
public partial class tblUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Your Email Id")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Your Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(18, ErrorMessage = "The password must be atleast 3 characters long", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Your Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(18, ErrorMessage = "The password must be atleast 3 characters long", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
}
```

### My view(Changepassword.cshtml)

```
@model MvcWebApplication1.Models.tblUser

<div class="container">
    <div class="row rowspace1">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "Login", "Home")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="CpassTitle">
            <h3>CHANGE PASSWORD</h3>
        </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Changepassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            
                <table class="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Old Password</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(pass => pass.Password)
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(pass => pass.Password)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="rowspace">
                        <td>New Password</td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(pass => pass.NewPassword)
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(pass => pass.NewPassword)</td>
                    </tr>
                  
                    <tr class="rowspace">
                        <td colspan="3" id="button">
                            <input type="submit" value="Change Password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="rowspace"><td colspan="3">@ViewBag.Message</td></tr>
                </table>
            
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on change password submit button I am getting a `NullReferenceException` in action method on line `userDetail.Password = login.NewPassword;`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Changepassword(tblUser login)
{
    UserDetailsEntities db = new UserDetailsEntities();
    var detail = db.tblUsers.Where(log => log.Password == login.Password).FirstOrDefault();
    if (detail != null)
    {
        var userDetail = db.tblUsers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == login.Email);
        userDetail.Password = login.NewPassword;
        
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.Message = "Record Inserted Successfully!";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Password not Updated!";
    }
    return View(login);
}
```

Comment: Make sure `userDetail` object is not null before updating the Password property value.

Comment: Your `FirstOrDefault` method is probably returning null when it finds no record for the email passed.

Comment: @Will SO should I remove **FirstorDefault** Method.

Comment: No. Just add a null check before accessing the properties (`if(userDetail!=null) { \\update password here }`). But you should find out why it is giving you no result. May be  your `login.Email` does not have a valid email address which you have in your db table. Put a breakpoint and inspect the variable values.

Comment: Yeah, what @Shyju said. Also, your view does not have a `HiddenFor` for the `Email` property of the model, so it will always be null in your HttpPost method and presumably is causing all this.

Comment: I have used HiddenFor for the email property of model in my view.But still it is not working. I have also tried the code .

Comment: Show us your stack trace.  But the fix for a `NullReferenceException` is always the same: *find the null object that is being dereferenced,* and fix your code so that it is no longer null, or it's no longer being dereferenced while it is null.

Comment: @Shyju Yes you were right.I added the null check and then I checked by putting a breakpoint my login.Email is returning null.

but the email id in my db table is correct.

The email id in my db table is 
Id - 1
Email - mehta.aman850@gmail.com
Password - aman

Answer (score -1):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Changepassword(tblUser login)
{
    UserDetailsEntities db = new UserDetailsEntities();
    var detail = db.tblUsers.Where(log => log.Password == login.Password).FirstOrDefault();

    // ADDED NULL CHECK HERE
    if (detail != null)
    {
        var userDetail = db.tblUsers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == login.Email);
         if(userDetail !=null)
         {
              userDetail.Password = login.NewPassword;

              db.SaveChanges();
              ViewBag.Message = "Record Inserted Successfully!";
         }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Password not Updated!";
    }
    return View(login);
}
```

Comment: Explain why this works.

Comment: bcos of the additional if statement.please upvote if it helps you

Comment: It's not *my* question, why would I need help?  Always include a bit of explanatory text with your answer; it's hard to tell just from a code dump what your answer is answering.

Comment: ok thanks for that. i was a bit busy

Comment: You're missing an `else`.

Answer (score -1):

Check ur db. It's either closing before you read from it or it's connecting to some other table.